# React Native: videos all load at once

Tags: javascript, react-native, performance, memory

In my application, I call 10 videos of 100MB each which are in Firesbase Storage. These videos are not displayed (their components are not rendered), the user must click the button specific to the video for the video to be displayed (rendered) and played. But the problem is that even with that, these 10 videos are all loaded as soon as the application launches and then my application starts to lag, the memory exceeds 1GB in a few seconds etc...

How can I make the video only load when I need it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the click function auto clicks on render, you could try add more conditions to the click

Comment: No it does not click automatically. I can verify this because when the button is pressed, I use `console.log()`, and it does not show anything...